# straight join in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, join

I have used left join in using zend framework/mysql using Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter. Does this also support straight join ? If yes, how do i do that? I tried checking in documentation. Couldn't find. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Zend source, it seems that there is no support for a `STRAIGHT_JOIN` when using `Zend_Db_Select`. You may however write the SQL statement yourself and then execute it directly using the DB adapter:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

//Taken from: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.select.fetchall
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE bug_id = ?';
$result = $db->fetchAll($sql, 2);
```

If you already have a complicated query using `Zend_Db_Select`, you can use the `__toString()` method and use that string as a basis for your modified query.

```
//Taken from: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.execute.tostring
$select = $db->select()->from('products');
$sql = $select->__toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this hack of Zend_Db_Select:

```
$select->from($tableName, array(new Zend_Db_Expr(' STRAIGHT_JOIN ' . $tableName . '.*'));
```

Hope this helps somebody.